# jquery str_replace not working

Tags: jquery, str-replace

I'm using jQuery to get the content of a div element and then add that content into a textarea on click using:

```
$('.editBody').one('click', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('two-columns');
  $(this).removeClass('editBody');
  var content = $(this).html();
  var page = $(this).data('page');
  var area = $(this).data('area');
  $(this).html('<form name="editTagline" method="POST" action="editcontent.php">' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="area" value="'+ area +'" />' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="'+ page +'" />' +
    '<textarea type="text" name="content" class="editBodytextarea">' + content + '</textarea>' +
    '<button id="submit">Save</button></form>');    
});
```

However, the textfield contains `<p>` tags. I have tried using `content.find("p").remove();` however this just breaks and doesn't output the textarea, just the paragraphs with `<p>` tags.. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it meant to be `one('click'...`? or `on('click'...`?

Comment: Can you post the html?

Comment: Yeah it is meant to be one :)

Comment: Have you tried .text instead of .html?  That should return you a result without the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var content = $(this).html();` will return you the raw HTML

However, `var content = $(this).text();` will return you just the text (minus the tags).  Give that a shot.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: it is still putting the tags into the textarea :S

Comment: @MarkP It seems to work over here. Are you meaning the tags display like literally "<p></p>" or that the text is formatted with white space?

Comment: @DanielCook Literally.

Comment: The HTML is literally a Div with some tags in. However I have solved the problem. I just used ckeditor to display the text area :)

Comment: Although, I'll accept your answer as the documentation provided states it should work :)